# Logic of the order of a login

Tags: java, file, class

I have a code that opens up a file to check if the username or password given by the user is in the file but the code shows a successful login when there really isn't one. I'm beginner at coding so I need some help fixing the error and using basic beginner coding with no complicated libraries or methods.

I get the following output, which shows that my program doesn't behave how I'd like it to:

```
USERNAME OR PASSWORD INCORRECT! TRY AGAIN
SUCCESSFUL, YOU ARE LOGGED IN!
```

Here is the code:

```
package login;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

public class Main {


    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        // TODO code application logic here.
        File file = new File("users.txt");
        Login newLogin = new Login(file);

        newLogin.checkLogin("word", "wordet");
    }

}


package login;

import java.io.File;
//library for file exception
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
//library for opening file
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Login {

    private File file;
    private ArrayList<String> usernames;
    private ArrayList<String> passwords;
    private int tries = 3;

    public Login(File file) {
        this.file = file;
        this.usernames = new ArrayList<String>();
        this.passwords = new ArrayList<String>();
        this.tries = 3;

    }

    public void readLines() throws FileNotFoundException{

        ArrayList<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();
        Scanner input = new Scanner(this.file);
        while (input.hasNextLine()){
            lines.add(input.nextLine());
        }
        input.close();

        usernames.clear();
        passwords.clear();
        for(int i = 0; i < lines.size(); i++) {
            if (i %2 == 0) {
                usernames.add(lines.get(i));
            } else {
                passwords.add(lines.get(i));
            }
        }
    }

    public void checkLogin(String user, String pass) throws FileNotFoundException{
        this.readLines();


       if (tries == 0){
           System.out.println("YOU HAVE TRIED TOO MANY TIMES!");
       } else {
            for(int i = 0; i < this.usernames.size(); i++) {
                if (this.usernames.contains(user)) {
                    if (passwords.get(i).equals(pass)) {
                        System.out.println("SUCCESSFUL, YOU ARE LOGGED IN!");
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("USERNAME OR PASSWORD INCORRECT! TRY AGAIN");
                        tries--;
                    }
                }
            }
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the error that you are getting.

Comment: Can you show the content of the file?

Comment: Please be more descriptive with the title!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Imagine you have two `"Darth Vader"` users, one with password `"Luke"`, the other with password `"Leia"`.
Also, suppose you want to only accept the one with the password `"Luke"`, and the `"Darth Vader"` with the password `"Leia"` comes first in your text file.

Notice that with your code, you will in your `for` loop, enter the `if (this.usernames.contains(user))`
for that `"Darth Vader"` with the wrong password, and thus, since he doesn't have the good password, it will display `"USERNAME OR PASSWORD INCORRECT! TRY AGAIN"` (you enter the else)!

Now, following the same logic, on the iteration of the `for` where we have the `"Darth Vader"` with the good password you will display `"SUCCESSFUL, YOU ARE LOGGED IN!"`

This is one solution:

```
  public void checkLogin(String user, String pass) throws FileNotFoundException{
        this.readLines();


        if (tries == 0){
            System.out.println("YOU HAVE TRIED TOO MANY TIMES!");
            return;
        }  
        int i = 0;
        for(; i < this.usernames.size(); i++) {
              if (!this.usernames.contains(user)) 
                  continue;

               if (passwords.get(i).equals(pass)) {
                   System.out.println("SUCCESSFUL, YOU ARE LOGGED IN!");
                   break;
               }            
        }
        if (i == this.usernames.size())
            System.out.println("USERNAME OR PASSWORD INCORRECT! TRY AGAIN");
  }
```

notice that i allowed myself to change some things in your code like removing the `else`, following the  `if (tries == 0)`, it makes the code look cleaner(and easier to debug).

Answer (score 3):

It looks like the issue is in this block of code.

```
           for(int i = 0; i < this.usernames.size(); i++) {
                if (this.usernames.contains(user)) {
                    if (passwords.get(i).equals(pass)) {
                        System.out.println("SUCCESSFUL, YOU ARE LOGGED IN!");
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("USERNAME OR PASSWORD INCORRECT! TRY AGAIN");
                        tries--;
                    }
                }
            }
```

When checking the username, you are just seeing if the user exists rather than if the current user "i" matches what was input. This should be changed to:

```
if (usernames.get(i).equals(user)) {
```

The logic is then:

Enumerate all users.
If the current username matches the test username, check password.
If the supplied password matches what is on record, login user in. Otherwise, the login failed.